# Send large POST request from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have to send a large POST request as part of a RESTful API call. The payload is around 80MB in size. When I try to send this in GAE Java, I get an exception saying it is not a permissible size because it is too large. What are the most common ways people send such large POST request? In my case, this request only happens very rarely, maybe once in 6 months or so. Nonetheless, I would need to have this feature.

Comment: It sounds like you are sending your post to a third party.  How you do this will depend on that third-party's API.  If their API doesn't allow breaking up data into chunks then I suspect you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests

The amount of data received by the application from requests. Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.

This includes:

data received by the application in secure requests and non-secure requests
uploads to the Blobstore
data received in response to HTTP requests by the URL fetch service

So write it to GCS or S3 or google sheets, docs etc... (anywhere that allows you to store a larger payload, then process this via a task queue.

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly, 1. let's say my 90MB data comes from my own website via HTTP POST. 2. My GAE Java servlet then stores it to GCS. 3. Submit a task queue that then loads this file from GCS and request POST to the remote server. 4. Receive response for the request and write to datastore

Comment: @jiminssy Not exactly. App Engine will not accept requests that large. Your website would have to use the cloud storage api (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) to upload a file. You could use a channel to monitor your uploads from inside your app engine application (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/watchAll) or trigger your appengine app once the upload is complete. Of course you could also chunk your file and upload the chunks through app engine and reassemble the data there somehow (which would probably involve cloud storage as well)

Comment: @konqi That is odd. I am able to send POST body that large to my local development GAE app and arrives with no exception in the respective servlet doPost. So in the real cloud instance this won't work eh?

Comment: @jiminssy That is correct. Don't get me started on what will work on the dev server but not in the cloud... Then again it makes sort of sense because you have a request deadline of 60 seconds. Uploading 80MB could take longer or most of that time. If you then wish to process the data you **will** run out of time.